# how much blob data can mysql handle?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table with `6 columns : 1 blob, 5 text` the number of entries can exceed 150,000 rows. Blob data will have size near 2Kb. 
Is it a good idea to create this table? Would there be any performance issues?
What different methods should I use ?

Answer (score 1):

That's less that a gigabyte?  MySQL can handle a terabyte or more.  MySQL could handle 10 blobs in each of 10 million rows.  Or more.  "Blob" is not the issue.

As for "performance issues", that's a question of what indexes you have, what queries you have, etc.  Please provide more details:  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; some sample queries; what type of data is involved (eg images); etc.

Comment: blob would have pdf and word files, queries would be select and insert.

Comment: By `PRIMARY KEY` or some other index?

Comment: as @RickJames tell - BLOB is not a issue, issue it is queries. Is it text columns - VARCHAR with search by =, or it really text with search by LIKE %xxx%

Comment: Now we are getting somwhere -- `LIKE `%xxx%'` on 150K wide rows will take a long time -- no index is useful.  Look into `FULLTEXT` indexing.

Comment: @RickJames index is `varchar` and search with `like`

Comment: An `INDEX` cannot be used with `LIKE` and a leading wildcard (`%`).  The entire table must be tediously scanned.  `FULLTEXT` _can_ find a _word_ really fast.

Comment: (Not to necro this, but...) We upgraded to MySQL 8.0.33 and began seeing unrecoverable corruption issues with tables that had BLOBs in them (in our non-PROD environments thankfully).  We have 35k records in our production database which hasn't yet exhibited the issue thankfully.  We never had any corruption issues on InnoDB tables prior to upgrading to 8.x and now we saw the same issue on the same table crop up in two different environments.  We're working to get BLOBs out of the production database.  But it is my anecdotally-based opinion that MySQL 8.x cannot handle BLOBs as robustly as 5.x.

Comment: @JustinN - Hmmm...  Please start a new Question with more details, such as `CREATE TABLE`, more stats on Blob and table sizes, types of queries (eg, do you `UPDATE` the blobs?), type of blobs (image / etc).  You mentioned 8.0.33; have you tried earlier versions of 8.0?

Comment: @RickJames I wasn't asking a question, I was making an observation.  Thanks.

Comment: @JustinN - OK.  If you ever have a _reproducible_ case of corruption, file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com .